# $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \Leftrightarrow$ for every monotonic sequence $x_n$ in $\text{dom}(f)$ converging to $x_0$, we have $\lim f(x_n) = f(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is continuous at $x_0 \Leftrightarrow$ for every monotonic sequence $x_n$ in $\text{dom}(f)$ converging to $x_0$, we have $\lim f(x_n) = f(x_0)$

Note: There is one answer for this already but it uses a different method than my attempted proof below, so please do not mark this as a duplicate.

Proof:

Take arbitrary $x_n$ converging to $x$. Then every sequence contains a monotonic sub-sequence, so take $x_{n_k}$ to be a monotonic sub-sequence of $x_n$. Since $x_n$ converges to x, then so does $x_{n_k}$.  Then by assumption $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x)$. This is where I am stuck and am not sure how to complete the idea now that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to argue by contradiction. Assume that $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$. Then there is $\epsilon_0>0$ and subsequence $(y_k)$ of $(x_n)$ so that 
$$|f(y_k) - f(x_0) | \ge \epsilon_0$$
for all $k$. This subsequence has a monotone subsequence $(z_l)$......

Comment: Two Questions. 1: Why did you need to take a subsequence $y_k$ and not just  $x_n$ itself. Secondly if $y_k$ has a monotone sub-sequence $z_l$ this shows that $f(z_l)$ converges to $f(x_0)$ but not that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$ so where is the contradiction.

Comment: 1. For example, $(x_n) = (0,1, 0,1, 0,1, \cdots)$ does not converges to $0$, but one does not have the stated inequality for this sequence. You need to take a subsequence $(y_k) = 1,1,1,1,1,\cdots)$. 2. Use the inequality. Can $f(z_l)$ converges to $f(x_0)$? @JamesDickens

Comment: @Artic Char we are assuming that $x_n$ converges.

Comment: @JamesDickens, yes, we are.

Comment: @Artic Char so then your example of $x_n$ doesn't fit the definition since it is not convergent?

Comment: We assume $x_n \to x_0$ and show that $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. To make a contradiction, we assume $x_n \to x_0$ and that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$. @JamesDickens

Answer (score 0):

## Hint

For every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{k_\ell}})_{\ell \in \mathbb N}$ of $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ with $f(x_{n_{k_\ell}}) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ (this can be proven similar to your idea, so that comes into play here)

It follows that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$. Can you see why?

PS: I hope this is not the prove mentioned in the other question.